# Complicated React Error: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatcher, reducers

I am getting this error whenever I submit a login attempt on my React/Redux Application. The full error that pops up in the browser window is as follows:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)or a class/function
(for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from 
the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.


Check the render method of `Router.Consumer`.
```

It of course also shows the block of code where it thinks the error occurred, but as we know this isn't always accurate and this is one of those times. The block it shows is from the **loginAction.js file** which looks like this...

```
import DOMAIN from "../constants/domain"

export default function loginAction(state){
    let user = null
    let login_destination = DOMAIN() + 'login'
    console.log("Before the fetch, the request is... POST " + login_destination)
    let login_object = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: state.username_input,
            password: state.password_input
        })
    }
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch(login_destination, login_object)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(json => user = json)
        .then(user => {
            console.log("Inside the LoginAction.js file. In final .then() block once a user model has been fetched")
            console.log(user)
            let userObj = {user: user.user, stocks: user.user_stocks}

            console.log(userObj) // THIS IS WHERE THE COMPILER SAYS THE ERROR OCCURS

            if (typeof(user) != "string"){ 
                dispatch({type: 'USER_LOGIN', payload: userObj})
            }
            else{
                dispatch({type: 'USER_LOGIN', payload: user})
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I've seen online that a lot of people are saying an error like this is usually do to an importing/exporting issue, but as you see here the **loginAction.js** file is set to export one thing only, and the file that`receives the action looks like this...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import loginAction from '../../dispatch_actions/loginAction.js';
import Signup from '../dispatchers/Signup';
import './css/LoginOrSignUp.css'


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return({
        failed_attempt: state.user.failed_attempt
    })
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return({

        submitLogin: (state) => {
            dispatch({type: 'LOAD_LOGIN'})
            dispatch(loginAction(state))
        }
        
    })
}
```

IThere is of course more code in the file shown above, but other than the button to login there is nothing else going on that's too crazy or confusing here. It is also worth mentioning that the dispatcher DOES in fact reach the reducer, as I have a console.log statement in there that keeps getting  hit, here's that file too incase it might help, as the final console.og statement is the last thing to get hit before the error

````
export default function manageUser(
    state= 
        {
            failed_attempt: {failed: false, reason: null},     // if a login attemot fails, this will be used to prompt a message
            isLoggedIn: false,  // determine whether these is a current user
            loading: false,     // true if fetching user from a login or signup
            name: null,         // user's name
            email: null,        // Kind of obvious
            gen_code: null,     // Exists only as a code emailed to a user upon sign up. Expires in 90 seconds
            targets: [null],    // stocks that user has targetted. Will be represented as an object array

     }, action){
        switch(action.type){
            // {type: LOAD_LOGIN}
            case('LOAD_LOGIN'):
                return ({
                    ...state, loaidng: true
                })

            // {type: "FAILURE", payload: <string> }
            case('FAILURE'):
                return ({
                    ...state, failed_attempt: {failed: true, reason: action.payload}
                })
                
            // {type: "USER_LOGIN", payload: <userObj from Rails Server>}
            // userObj will look like this...
            //             
            //              _____________________________________________________________________________
            //              | user:                                                                     |
            //              |  {username: <input>, password_digest: <hidden>}                           |
            //              | stocks:                                                                   |
            //              |  [ <array of ints> ]                                                      |
            //              |___________________________________________________________________________|     
            //
            // 
            case('USER_SIGNUP'):
            case('USER_LOGIN'):
                console.log("Inside User Reducer, LOGIN Case. Payload below")
                console.log(action.payload)
                return({
                    ...state, failed_attempt: {failed: false, reason: null}, isLoggedIn: true, loading: false, name: action.payload.user.username, stocks: action.payload.stocks
                })
            default:
                return ({
                    ...state
                })
            
            
        }


}```
````

Comment: I think might be at someplace object is being used to render. But as mentioned in the error, a string or array should be used to render.

Comment: Right, I understand that but I really have no idea where it's using an object. The only object getting thrown into this is userObj which is set to the payload which is fine, this code is essentially identical to the sign-up or fetch-session actions I have and those both work, so I'm just lost as to where this is even truly occuring

Comment: Maybe you can console log the props you are getting from redux store after sign up and check whether its having an object and are u using that object to render UI.